# Filtering pandas dataframe using output from idxmax function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame with more than one numerical columns and would like to find a maximum across row so I did below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(100000, 10)))
max_series = df.max(axis=1)

# O/P is a pd.Series like below

0     0.741459
1     0.995978
2     0.978618
3     0.973057
4     0.838006
        ...
```

Next we want to find the index of maximum value. So I did below,

```
filter_ = df.idxmax(axis=1)

# O/P
0     3
1     8
2     7
3     5
4     1
 ..
```

Now using the `filter_` on DataFrame I want to achieve the result same as `max_series` variable and without using the `pd.DataFrame.max(axis=1)`

So I tried below,

```
df.loc[:, filter_]
```

or

```
df.filter(items=filter_, axis=1)
```

but both give me

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (100000, 100000) and data type float64
```

I don't need a `100000x100000 matrix`, I just need my `max_series` which is `100000x1`

So how do I filter the DataFrame using the `filter_` and get the `pd.Series` of maximum across rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a faster solution:

```py
%%time
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(100000, 10)))
max_series = df.max(axis=1)

filter_  = df.idxmax(axis=1)

unique_cols = filter_.unique()
max_series_ = pd.concat([df.loc[df.index.isin(filter_[filter_ == col].index), col] for col in unique_cols]).sort_index()
    

from pandas.testing import assert_series_equal

assert_series_equal(max_series_, max_series)
```

Maybe it can be even optimized further.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solutions,

```
filter_ = df.idxmax(axis=1)
df.apply(lambda row: row[filter_.loc[row.name]], axis=1)
```